# iOS push notification success using command prompt but not in php

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

Working on CMD. (Notification send)

```
curl -v -d '{"callerID":"remote@example.com"}' --http2 --cert
vCert.pem:12678 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/33feaba07f2a67ff9cd7ca8007f0e
```

But not working in PHP (notification not send).

```
$cmd = "curl -v -d '{\"callerID\":\"remote@example.com\"}' --http2 --cert voipCert.pem:123456789 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/33feaba07f2a67ff9cd7ca8007f0e";
exec($cmd, $output, $retval);
```

Comment: try to not escape double quote if you are using single quote. e.g. `'{"hello": "world"}'`

Comment: am trying like this way but still not working.                                                              
>curl -v -d '{"callerID":"remote@example.com"}' --http2 --cert voipCert.pem:123456789 https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/33feab49a6218e0bddecb3f1078

Comment: edit the question with the error you are getting

Comment: Actually showing no errors but push notification not send to the device whereas using CMD push notification send to the respected device.